# Removing unwanted photos in slick slider product thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

I am new to Javascript, could anyone help me with the following question? 
I have a product with various color variations, so I made the color swatch in such way that only the photos of the selected color are shown using the display: none css method. However, in the mobile version, the not-displayed photos are still taking up place in the thumbnail slider(not shown, but occupying a space, which messes up the slider), it seems like it is using Slick Slider that has a slick-data-index to rank the files, I am trying to use the slickRemove function to get rid of the unwanted colors but I have not had any luck, could anyone help me on how to remove the not-selected colors, your help will be much appreciated, thank you!

```
var getfeaturedimage = document.getElementById("FeaturedImage-product-template");
  var getfeaturedimagevalue = getfeaturedimage.getAttribute("color-option");
  var thumbnailLi2 = $('.product-single__thumbnails-item[color-option="' + getfeaturedimagevalue + '"]');
         var colorshown2 = $('.product-single__thumbnail-image[color-option="' + getfeaturedimagevalue + '"]');
          $('.product-single__thumbnails-item').css('display','none')
          $('.product-single__thumbnail-image').css('display','none')
          $('.product-single__thumbnails-item').css('clear','none')

          var $notcolor = document.querySelectorAll('li[data-slick-index]:not([data-slick-index="getfeaturedimagevalue"])');
          $notcolor.slick('slickRemove','i');

          $(thumbnailLi2).css('display','')
          $(colorshown2).css('display','')
```

Page View

[image]